# Automatically split ambiguous bases proportionally to A, C, G or T

Tags: r, bioinformatics

In Biostrings, I have loaded a fasta file of 427,351 DNA sequences of 11 nucleotides in length.

```
my.seq<-readDNAStringSet("my.fasta", "fasta")
```

Then, I generated a matrix which counts the total number of a particular nucleotide at each of the 11 positions:

```
my.pfm<-consensusMatrix(my.seq)
>my.pfm

   [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]  [,11]
A 113370 120216 109984  40729 150681     11 340936  41684  75946 150648  84290
C  98927 107171  99251 110222  76286 427265  25668 256664 191010 103889 139625
G 118545  93632  95588  74975 138899      9     95  91414  64966  66896 113694
T  96509 106332 122528 201425  61485     66  60652  37589  95429 105918  89741
M      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
R      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
W      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
S      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Y      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
K      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
V      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
H      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
D      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
B      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
N      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
-      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
+      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
.      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

What you can see is that I have a single "N" nucleotide present in one of my sequences in the 11th position (row N, column 11).

The next step is to make a position matrix frequency, however, this is only possible when the column sums of rows "A", "C", "G", and "T" are equal.  In the above example column 11's sum would be one less than all of the others due to the N base.

What is the best way to write the consensusMatrix function so that all non-A,C,G,and T bases are appropriately categorized as either a A, C, G, T or a combination of any them?  Since N represents any of the 4 bases, then for each instance of N, 0.25 would be added to the A, C, G and T values of column 11.  However should one write the function for all the other non-A,C,G and T nucleotides so they are appropriately assigned at the right proportion to A,C,G,T?

For example Y= either C or T so for each instance of Y, 0.5 would be added to C and 0.5 would be added to the T value of that column.  I can see a problem if we have something like a V code as this can either be G, A or C, in that case 0.33333 would be added to each instance of V for that column.

What I have tried:

```
my.pfm<-consensusMatrix(my.seq,ambiguityMap=IUPAC_CODE_MAP)


Error in .local(x, as.prob, shift, width, ...) :
  unused argument (ambiguityMap = c("A", "C", "G", "T", "AC", "AG", "AT", "CG", "CT", "GT", "ACG", "ACT", "AGT", "CGT", "ACGT"))
```

As I  understand there should be some kind of character vector that tells the function what to do when anything other than A,C,G,T are counted, but I can't seem to figure it out.

The idea here is to have some kind of defining function that will work no matter how many and what kind of ambiguity codes are encountered in the future.

Note: I don't want to delete whole sequences that have anything other than A,C,G,or T in them from the data set.

Comment: I would advise you to exclude the sequence containing the N from your dataset.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Forgive me for being more or less ignorant of this field, but what does "appropriately categorize non-nucleotides ATCG" entail?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I think we want to have colsums for non ATCG rows, divide by 4 and add to ATCG rows.

Comment: (1) Exclude Ns, (2) normalise all columns to 1 (or an appropriate value) so that, instead of having absolute counts, you have proportions/percentages/… of A, C, G, and T.

Comment: Like @JackAidley said. Exclude the single sequence with an 'N'. Most likely the sequencer couldn't determine the base at that position in that sequence. If you really want to include it, you could either go back and examine the sequence data for that sequences (mapped reads or trace file etc). Other option is to impute the most likely missing base by extracting all the sequences that are 100% identical except at position 11, and then examine the proportion of `A,C,T,G` at that position for the otherwise identical sequences, assigning the `N` to the most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, but from the comments it seems like you are asking wrong question for this type of data.

```
#get sum of non ACGT and divide by 4
props <- colSums(my.pfm[ !rownames(my.pfm) %in% c("A","C","G","T"),]) / 4

#add it back to ACGT rows
t(
  apply(
    my.pfm[ rownames(my.pfm) %in% c("A","C","G","T"),], 1, function(i)
      props + i))

#output
#     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]     [,11]
# A 113370 120216 109984  40729 150681     11 340936  41684  75946 150648  84290.25
# C  98927 107171  99251 110222  76286 427265  25668 256664 191010 103889 139625.25
# G 118545  93632  95588  74975 138899      9     95  91414  64966  66896 113694.25
# T  96509 106332 122528 201425  61485     66  60652  37589  95429 105918  89741.25
```

Comment: If you do use this approach, you should code in the proportions for the other ambiguity codes correctly, rather than just dividing evenly for all of them. i.e. R gets split 50/50 between A and G, etc.

Comment: The approach from zx8754 indeed works, however, I later discovered that the next step requires the matrix to be in integer format, so fractional numbers won't work. I think I will need figure out how to exclude whole lines of sequence that have anything other than A,C,G or T in the string as suggested by Jack and Simon.  So I'm now trying to figure out how to do that.